# PHP - Extract Text from Title tag

Tags: php, html, tags, title

I need to extract the text between html title tag example :(content, I wrote the followig code and it works fine

```
/ Main area
$link = "http://www.fonecta.fi";
gettitle($link);
// End of main area

function gettitle($link)
{
$text = file_get_contents($link);
preg_match_all('/<title>.*?<\/title>/is', $text, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $m)
{
    echo htmlentities($m)."<br />";
}
}
```

Howerver, it doesn't display the foreign letters in correct manner for example the output I got of this word (Henkilöt) is (HenkilÃ¶t). Any advise how solve this problem?

Code is written in PHP.

Comment: don't htmlentities() it and convert your page to UTF-8

Comment: Why are you doing `preg_match_all` and `foreach`? A page should only have 1 `title` tag. Try `/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/is`

Comment: Yes, the commen is one title, however, if it happens that more than one title tag is exist, then I will need to extract them all and appy some hueristics..

Comment: @putvande He might be extracting title from XML or RSS page, where title tag exists in multiple forms.

Comment: @Dave, how can I do that, any specific command or code? thanks

Comment: You could start by using google